# how to get unique identity from users logged in with open id google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, openid

I have just come across Google App engine and am trying to develop a site on it.  Part of the site should allow users to log in.
I plan to offer two options.

1. log in using my own implemented account manager with sessions and whatnot - not to hard according to  [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675371/google-app-engine-sessions-now-supported)
2. Log in using an open ID account

When using my own log in form I can force a unique identity to be created through an email address/user name field, etc.  but how can I get a unique identity from an open id user?  Are they guarantied to have supplied an email - as in will the user service give me a user object that is guarantied to have an email?

Thanks a lot for any advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the unique identifier for a user, use `User#getUserId()`.

> Returns an opaque string that uniquely identifies the user represented by this User object.

In case of open ID account, you can also use `User#getFederatedIdentity()`, however, I would say that it does not have to return always the unique identifier.

> There are two flavors of provider types: direct providers like Google and Yahoo! require only a generic federated identity that has no username associated with it.
>
> In contrast, Flickr, WordPress, Blogger, and LiveJournal are known as username providers because all require you to provide a URL which does.

See more details [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/openid#ip).

Anyway there is also a possibility to store the user object as a whole. This is supported out of the box by App Engine and Datastore.